# Is it possible to have gitlab CI trigger another pipeline?

Tags: automation, gitlab-ci

I'm new to gitlab CI so I'm still trying to get my head around it but I'm wondering if it's possible to do the following?

Developers work in REPO A

QA work in REPO B

When the pipeline from REPO A kicks off is it possible to have it trigger the pipeline from REPO B with a command and pass variables?

That way Developers in REPO A can work on their part of the project e.g. login form but REPO B can contain the entire end to end suite of tests for all features, so if a new team is formed and work on REPO C they can also trigger tests in REPO B.

This would mean QA always work in one repo, and if another repo wants to do a deployment they can call their subset of tests but nightly REPO B can run the full end to end suite with different browsers, devices etc.

Answer (score 22):

There is the concept of "Multi-Project Pipelines" in "Downstream pipelines" which exactly allow your desired behaviour.

See:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#multi-project-pipelines

In your case this would be in Project A and B

```yaml
externalTest: 
    variables: 
        ENVIRONMENT: aVariableValue
    stage: deploy 
    trigger: 
        project: my-namespace/repo-b
```

Comment: Although it isn't very clear from the GitLab Docs it is helpful to understand that this feature using the "trigger" keyword is only available to Premium GitLab user account.  It is not available to  the "Free" user accounts.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/199224
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/63497

Comment: The only issue with this is, that I would have to create the `trigger: my-namespace/repo-b` for each repository that will be triggering. Which isnt that bad, but I was hoping to reduce the duplication with a solution

Comment: @whitestryder This feature is now free. And great if you ask me! It just works.

Comment: @secustor what is namespace? And where is the root of namespace?

Comment: namespace is the path of the Gitlab project as seen in the URL of the project. eg. https://gitlab.cncf.ci/kubernetes/kubernetes  has the namespace `kubernetes`. Therefore the trigger will be `kubernetes/kubernetes`

Comment: The link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html#creating-multi-project-pipelines-from-gitlab-ciyml is outdated

Comment: here example for this feature https://youtu.be/FQDLJ9XQAYo?feature=shared

Answer (score 7):

There is a way in the documents of [Triggering pipelines through the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#when-used-with-multi-project-pipelines) which gives us the ability of triggering another pipeline using [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/) in the current running pipeline:

> This way of triggering can only be used when invoked inside
>   .gitlab-ci.yml, and it creates a dependent pipeline relation visible
>   on the pipeline graph. For example:
>
> ```
> build_docs:   
>     stage: deploy   
>     script:
>         - curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form ref=master https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/9/trigger/pipeline   
>     only:
>         - tags
> ```
>
> Pipelines triggered that way also expose a special variable:
>   `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=pipeline`.

If you want to trigger **REPO B** pipeline from *REPO A* and *REPO C*, please remember that you must replace the **REPO B** project id in the above URL instead of example id.

Comment: How to specify stage for REPO B pipeline?
for example I want run only test stage in REPO B when REPO A pushed

Answer (score 2):

@doctor-wh, please read this article from GitLab team, it helps me in the way I needed.

I had needed to start CI process of REPO A, when someone push their codes on REPO B which was related  to REPO A, so  it was amazingly helpful for me.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html

hope it will help you.

Comment: does anyone know if it is possible to authenticate/know which other project initiated the trigger? I want to be able to verify details that are passed in based on the caller

Comment: @cgmckeever if you want to see what is the chain of project call after the trigger will be called, I suggest to call the trigger one time and then you can see easily the visualize path of your trigger in the gitlab CI /CD pipeline details.

Comment: The link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html is outdated

Comment: The link is outdated!

Comment: Thanks @Ouss for letting us Know, here is the archived link:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html